# Iterating function for a list of variables

Tags: r

For the data frame below

```
df <- data.frame(HOD = c("AA","BB","CC","AA","BB","AA","CC","BB","AA","CC","AA","BB","CC"),
                 Dept = c("CA","HR","CA","HR","HR","CA","HR","HR","CA","CA","HR","CA","CA"),
                 Manager = c("AKASH","MANU","AMAN","SANU","NISH","KAMAL","VEER","SANIL","SAMEER","KANU","NUKUL","KUNAL","RAMIT"),
                 PF = c("Yes","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No","Yes","No","Yes","Yes","Yes","No"),
                 Yearlybonus=c(6946,5871,0,7173,2161,3008,0,3025,4323,4196,0,5594,2313),
                 Quaterlybonus=c(2683,3846,0,2391,6716,6012,5479,3869,3764,0,4632,0,2371),
                 monthlybonus=c(4453,6466,2811,6845,4377,2617,0,7631,7761,2944,6270,3534,5856))
```

```
 t1 <- melt(df[Dept == "CA"],id.vars=c("Manager","PF","Yearlybonus", "Quaterlybonus", "monthlybonus"))
```

now i want to loop this for list of var(HOD)

Comment: your `t1` needs debugging.  Moreover, please include a desired output for sample given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lapply` or `map`. Apparently, they do the same thing but `purrr` allows for slightly cooler syntax.

```
hod=unique(df$HOD)
lapply(hod, function(x) {
  return(filter(df, HOD==x))
})

library(purrr)
map(hod, ~filter(df, HOD==.))

[[1]]
  HOD Dept Manager  PF Yearlybonus Quaterlybonus monthlybonus
1  AA   CA   AKASH Yes        6946          2683         4453
2  AA   HR    SANU Yes        7173          2391         6845
3  AA   CA   KAMAL  No        3008          6012         2617
4  AA   CA  SAMEER  No        4323          3764         7761
5  AA   HR   NUKUL Yes           0          4632         6270

[[2]]
  HOD Dept Manager  PF Yearlybonus Quaterlybonus monthlybonus
1  BB   HR    MANU  No        5871          3846         6466
2  BB   HR    NISH Yes        2161          6716         4377
3  BB   HR   SANIL Yes        3025          3869         7631
4  BB   CA   KUNAL Yes        5594             0         3534

[[3]]
  HOD Dept Manager  PF Yearlybonus Quaterlybonus monthlybonus
1  CC   CA    AMAN Yes           0             0         2811
2  CC   HR    VEER  No           0          5479            0
3  CC   CA    KANU Yes        4196             0         2944
4  CC   CA   RAMIT  No        2313          2371         5856
```

As requested, here is a function that can be fed a data frame and also turns the Dept column into two separate columns.

```
library(dplyr)
get_list=function(dt) {
  hod=unique(dt$HOD)
  lapply(hod, function(x) {
    return(filter(dt, HOD==x) %>%
             pivot_longer(Dept, names_to="variable"))
  })
}

get_list=function(dt) {
  hod=unique(dt$HOD)
  map(hod, ~filter(dt, HOD==.) %>%
        pivot_longer(Dept, names_to="variable"))
}
get_list(df)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 5 x 8
  HOD   Manager PF    Yearlybonus Quaterlybonus monthlybonus variable value
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>    <chr>
1 AA    AKASH   Yes          6946          2683         4453 Dept     CA   
2 AA    SANU    Yes          7173          2391         6845 Dept     HR   
3 AA    KAMAL   No           3008          6012         2617 Dept     CA   
4 AA    SAMEER  No           4323          3764         7761 Dept     CA   
5 AA    NUKUL   Yes             0          4632         6270 Dept     HR   

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  HOD   Manager PF    Yearlybonus Quaterlybonus monthlybonus variable value
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>    <chr>
1 BB    MANU    No           5871          3846         6466 Dept     HR   
2 BB    NISH    Yes          2161          6716         4377 Dept     HR   
3 BB    SANIL   Yes          3025          3869         7631 Dept     HR   
4 BB    KUNAL   Yes          5594             0         3534 Dept     CA   

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  HOD   Manager PF    Yearlybonus Quaterlybonus monthlybonus variable value
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>       <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>    <chr>
1 CC    AMAN    Yes             0             0         2811 Dept     CA   
2 CC    VEER    No              0          5479            0 Dept     HR   
3 CC    KANU    Yes          4196             0         2944 Dept     CA   
4 CC    RAMIT   No           2313          2371         5856 Dept     CA
```

Comment: Actually i want to create a function because i have apply it for a big data i have so that i can run it in my chunks in rmd, also i want to select columns from my list of columns

Comment: Is this what you want?

Comment: i think may be i am not able to make you understand my requirement , sorry